# Export query result to Json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Using the `FOR JSON AUTO` statement, if you can with another perfect method, how can I convert the result of the select that I set as an example in the following Json format and so on with the rest of the results?

According to the category I would have 1 or more requirements inside of the Json:

- Category 1 is formed if **title** has S
- Category 2 is formed if **domain** and **origin** have S
- Category 3 is formed if all the others are N but **Origin** is S
- Category 4 is formed with all the requirements in N

Data:

```
id          Titulo Dominio Documento fiscalizacion Informe Investigacion Legajo Origen Categoria
    ----------- ------ ------- --------- ------------- ------- ------------- ------ ------ --------------------------------------------------
    953922      N      N       N         N             N       N             N      S      3
    950794      N      N       N         N             N       N             N      S      3
    957140      N      N       N         N             N       N             N      S      3
    86068       N      N       N         N             N       N             N      N      4
    93300       N      N       N         N             N       N             N      N      4
    82286       N      S       N         N             N       N             N      S      2
    92476       S      N       N         N             N       N             N      N      1
```

output:

```
{
 "id": 86068       ,
 "Categoria": 4,
 "Requisitos": [
     "Titulo",
     "Dominio",
     "Doumento",
     "fiscalizacion",
     "Informe",
     "Investigacion",
     "Legajo",
     "Origen" ]
 },

{
 "id": 92476       ,
 "Categoria": 1,
 "Requisitos": [
     "Titulo"
     ]
 },

{
 "id": 950794       ,
 "Categoria": 3,
 "Requisitos": [
     "Origen" ]
 },
```

Comment: The "output:"  seem to not have any values "S" or "N".  Is that by purpose? What is JSON to do with no values?

Comment: S or N determine within the requirements which columns to include

Comment: So the above "output:" would not have "Titulo" nor "Dominio"... ??

Comment: As an example add to category 4 where all the columns are N that is the requirement to belong

Comment: Please add an example "output:" for category not equal to 4, so that we can see the difference.

Comment: @donPablo More examples were added according to the result of the query

Comment: Thanks for the additional examples.  Still trying to clarify requirements.  What output for an ID with Titulo=S and Documento=S and Legajo=S ?? Would it be Category 1? Would the two additional Requisitos be shown?

Comment: @donPablo Category 1: titulo S or dominio S or investigacion S
Category 2: Documento S or legajo S or informe S or fiscalizacion
Category 3: origen S
Category 4: all N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your resultset as a union of the 4 categories (each one with its rules) and then convert everything to json:

```
declare @tmp table(id int, Titulo char(1), Dominio char(1), Documento char(1), fiscalizacion char(1), Informe char(1), Investigacion char(1), Legajo char(1), Origen char(1), Categoria char(1))
insert into @tmp values    
     (953922      ,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','S',3)
    ,(950794      ,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','S',3)
    ,(957140      ,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','S',3)
    ,(86068       ,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N',4)
    ,(93300       ,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N',4)
    ,(82286       ,'N','S','N','N','N','N','N','S',2)
    ,(92476       ,'S','N','N','N','N','N','N','N',1)

--  Categoria = 1
select id, categoria,json_query(replace(QUOTENAME(
   case when Titulo ='S' then quotename('Titulo','"')                + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Dominio ='S' then  quotename('Dominio','"')             + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Investigacion ='S' then  quotename('Investigacion','"') + ', ' else '' end 
 ),', ]',']') ) as Requisitos
from @tmp 
where Categoria = 1

UNION ALL 

--Categoria = 2
    select id, categoria,json_query(replace(QUOTENAME(
 + case when Documento ='S' then  quotename('Documento','"')         + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when fiscalizacion ='S' then  quotename('fiscalizacion','"') + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Informe ='S' then  quotename('Informe','"')             + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Legajo ='S' then  quotename('Legajo','"')               + ', ' else '' end 
 ),', ]',']') ) as Requisitos
from @tmp where Categoria = 2

UNION ALL

--Categoria = 3 
select id, categoria,json_query(case when Origen ='S' then  quotename(quotename('Origen','"')  )  + ', ' else '' end) as Requisitos
from @tmp 
where Categoria = 3 

UNION ALL

--Categoria = 4 
select id, categoria,json_query(replace(QUOTENAME(
   case when Titulo ='N' then quotename('Titulo','"')                + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Dominio ='N' then  quotename('Dominio','"')             + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Documento ='N' then  quotename('Documento','"')         + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when fiscalizacion ='N' then  quotename('fiscalizacion','"') + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Informe ='N' then  quotename('Informe','"')             + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Investigacion ='N' then  quotename('Investigacion','"') + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Legajo ='N' then  quotename('Legajo','"')               + ', ' else '' end 
 + case when Origen ='N' then  quotename('Origen','"')               + ', ' else '' end 
 ),', ]',']') ) as Requisitos
from @tmp where Categoria = 4

for json auto , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Results:

```
{
    "id": 92476,
    "categoria": "1",
    "Requisitos": ["Titulo"]
},
{
    "id": 82286,
    "categoria": "2",
    "Requisitos": []
},
{
    "id": 953922,
    "categoria": "3",
    "Requisitos": ["Origen"]
},
{
    "id": 950794,
    "categoria": "3",
    "Requisitos": ["Origen"]
},
{
    "id": 957140,
    "categoria": "3",
    "Requisitos": ["Origen"]
},
{
    "id": 86068,
    "categoria": "4",
    "Requisitos": ["Titulo",
    "Dominio",
    "Documento",
    "fiscalizacion",
    "Informe",
    "Investigacion",
    "Legajo",
    "Origen"]
},
{
    "id": 93300,
    "categoria": "4",
    "Requisitos": ["Titulo",
    "Dominio",
    "Documento",
    "fiscalizacion",
    "Informe",
    "Investigacion",
    "Legajo",
    "Origen"]
}
```

Comment: How can I add the Json start and end brackets? [ ]

Comment: @Sebastian just remove WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER